# RNGCryptoServiceProvider does not produce same hash for same PWD,Salt,Iteration combination

Tags: c#, cryptography, hash, pbkdf2

Oki So I want to hash my password by appending random salt in .Net . The inbuilt classes I m using for this purpose are **RNGCryptoServiceProvider** - to generate the random salt and **Rfc2898DeriveBytes** - to hash the actual password.

But when I call the GetBytes() function of Rfc2898DeriveBytes for the same combination of passwordString, SaltBytes & Iteration count the result is different.
I m pasting my code for reference

```
    public class PBKDF2Implementation
    {
        int minSaltSize = 32;
        int maxSaltSize = 64;


        public string CreateHash(string plainText , out string  salt)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            int saltSize = random.Next(minSaltSize, maxSaltSize);

            // Allocate a byte array, which will hold the salt.
            byte[] saltBytes = new byte[saltSize];

            // Initialize a random number generator.
            RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
            // Fill the salt with cryptographically strong byte values.
            rng.GetNonZeroBytes(saltBytes);

            string strSalt = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(saltBytes);
            //string strSalt = System.Convert.ToBase64String(saltBytes);
            salt = strSalt;

            Console.WriteLine(saltBytes.Count());
            Console.WriteLine(strSalt);

            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pwdGen = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(plainText, saltBytes, 1000);

            // generate an RC2 key
            byte[] key = pwdGen.GetBytes(32);

            Console.WriteLine(System.Convert.ToBase64String(key));
            return System.Convert.ToBase64String(key);
        }

        public bool CompareHash(string plainText, string salt, string hashValue)
        {

            byte[] saltBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(salt);
            //byte[] saltBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(salt);

            Console.WriteLine(saltBytes.Count());
            Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(saltBytes));

            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pwdGen = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(plainText, saltBytes, 1000);

            // generate an RC2 key
            byte[] key = pwdGen.GetBytes(32);

            Console.WriteLine(System.Convert.ToBase64String(key));
            return System.Convert.ToBase64String(key) == hashValue;
        }
    }
```

And in my test class I hav this function

```
    [Test]
    public void shouldGenerateConsistentHash()
    {
        PBKDF2Implementation cPbkdf2Implementation = new PBKDF2Implementation();
        string salt;
        string hashValue = cPbkdf2Implementation.CreateHash("password", out salt);

        bool result = cPbkdf2Implementation.CompareHash("password", salt, hashValue);
        Assert.IsTrue(result) ;
    }
```

The test fails.
But if in the above class PBKDF2Implementation if I replace the lines 
System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString with System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString 
and 
System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes with System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes

The test passes. any idea why is this happening?
The reason I want to make it work with ASCII encoding is because the same DB in which this hashvalue is stored will also be used by a PHP application & the hashvalue produced by PBKDF2 implementaion of PHP matches the hashvalue of Rfc2898DeriveBytes only if the salt encoding is ASCII.

Here is the PHP implementation of the same 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php#101540

Answer (score 7):

1. Avoid using strings with crypto. Use byte arrays, i.e. `byte[]`
2. If you must use strings take **great care** of encodings. They will bite you 9 times out of 10;

E.g.

```
byte [] data = new byte [] { 65, 0, 65 };
var s = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString (data);
```

what is `s` value ?

Answer: "A"

If you ask the `byte[]` out of the same string you'll get: `byte [1] { 65 }`, which is not the same as the original and won't work for most cryptographic usage.

Base64 is safer since it will keep every byte intact.

Comment: Should'nt value of s be "A A" and if I get the byte array out of s it is {65,0,65} . 
code that I tried

static void Main(string[] args)
{
   byte[] data = new byte[] { 65, 0, 65 };
   var s = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
   Console.WriteLine("S=" + s);
   byte[] newData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
   Console.WriteLine(newData.Count());
   Console.WriteLine("Printing Bytes");
   newData.ToList().ForEach(byt =>
  {
                      Console.WriteLine(byt);
  }
                );
}
  
Out put is
S=A A
3
Printing Bytes
65
0
65

Comment: I tried with Mono. Anyway the main point is that the `Encoding` classes do **not** guarantee identical roundtrips, e.g. non-printable ASCII characters. As such they are problematic for any use, like cryptography, that depends on getting identical values.

Comment: @poupou It was probably a Mono bug. Mono 3.0.2 works correctly. `echo "Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(new byte [] { 65, 0, 65 })).Length);" | csharp` gives 3 .Net is not fooled by `\0`. ASCII is still not a great idea, but it's not THAT bad. I think you should remove the incorrect information from your answer.

Comment: Another big problem with `Encoding.ASCII` is that it silently replaces every byte above 127 with a question mark - that's about half of them.